# Неполучается импортировать модуль PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Начал изучать pyqt и в самом начало столкнулся с проблемой, не получается импортировать PyQt5 и любую его составляющею, использовал я pycharm.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QPushButton("Push Me")
window.show()

app.exec()
```

А в итоге получаю:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
```

Хотя, запуская тот же код в консоле используя python3 - все работает.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: У PyCharm собственное виртуальное окружение. Надо туда пакет ставить. Ну либо его перенастроить чтобы он использовал системный Питон.

Comment: https://coderoad.ru/20082367/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-PyQt5-%D0%B2-Pycharm